# What happens internally when a module is extended in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
Foo = Module.new

class MyClass
  include Foo
end
```

When a module is included in a class, an anonymous proxy class is created and set as MyClass's superclass.

```
MyClass.ancestors => [MyClass, Foo, ...]
```

But what happens **internally** when a module is extended? How does Ruby handle this?

Comment: What do you mean, internally? If you want (and need) this level of detail, you can read source code directly

Comment: i dont need the actual cpp implementation. i am reading abt ruby object model. i did get inclusion of module and i specified it above in the question. but i couldnt find anything definite abt extending a module. i want to know it theoretically abt how its implemented.

Comment: Mike Li's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you ask is `Object#extend`

So with `extend`, I can **include** any module's methods into that object.
For example I have a module called HelperModule:

```
module HelperModule
  def foo
    puts "from module helper"
  end
end
```

#### Usage Example 1:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.extend HelperModule
obj.foo                  # => "from module helper"
```

#### Usage Example 2:

```
class MyClass
  extend HelperModule
end
MyClass.foo              # => "from module helper"
```

**Internally**, according to [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A376YAK):

> **Object#extend() is simply a shortcut that includes a module in the receiver’s eigenclass.**

---

A brief explanation of ruby's methods call :

1. find the object's class, see if the method defined there
2. find that class's superclass, see if the method defined there

---

```
obj 
 |
 | class
 |                     superclass                  superclass
 --->  ObjectClass  --------------> SuperClass1 --------------> SuperClass2 ....
```

The detailed explanation about eigenclass and method call path, please reference this awesome book [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A376YAK)

Thanks

Comment: Isn't he talking about `Object#include`?

Comment: He said he knows what happens when you include, but he was unclear on extend.

Also, this is correct. The eigenclass is what's key.

Answer (score 0):

> Whats happens internally when a module in extended in Ruby?

When a module `M` is included in a class `C`, an anonymous proxy class `⟦M′⟧` (called an *include class*) is created such that its method table pointer points to `M`'s method table. (Same for the constant table and module variables.) `⟦M′⟧`'s superclass is set to `C`'s superclass and `C`'s superclass is set to `⟦M′⟧`.

Also, if `M` includes other modules, the process is applied recursively.

Actually, that's just the default behavior. What *really* happens is that `include` calls `M.append_features(C)`, and you can customize all of that behavior by overriding that method.

I find [the source code of `Module#append_features` in Rubinius](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/module.rb#L89-174) quite readable.

Comment: no offense meant but thats just what i have specified in the question regarding 'include'. I want to know what happens when we 'extend' a module.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.extend SomeModule` is the same as `obj.eigenclass.include SomeModule` (*Note*: this is just pseudocode, but you will get the idea...).

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, Ruby's `include` method will emulate inheritance: it will allow the including class access to the included module's instance methods, variables and constants as if they had been defined in the including class itself. Ruby does this by creating an anonymous proxy class (known as an eigenclass or singleton class), as you mentioned, which references the included module, and inserting it into the ancestors of the including class as the immediate superclass. This is what is known as a *mixin* in Ruby.

Using `extend`, however, interacts with the singleton class a little bit more:

```
module Foo
  def baz
    'baz'
  end
end

module Blah
  def blah
    'blah'
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Foo
  include Blah
  def self.magic
    'magic'
  end
end
```

Extending `Foo` in `Bar` is identical (right down to its implementation in C) to saying

```
Bar.singleton_class.send( :include, Foo )
```

This means that it is the singleton class of `Bar` in which the methods and constants of `Foo` are essentially embedded, and thus class `Bar`, being an instance of its singleton class, will inherit this new functionality as so-called 'class' methods. In Ruby, modules and classes can only have instance methods, and thus the creation of a 'class' method will actually just create an instance method in the class's singleton class, to be inherited in this manner.

```
Bar.baz
# => 'baz'
Bar.magic
# => 'magic'
Bar.blah
# => NoMethodError
Bar.new.baz
# => NoMethodError
Bar.new.magic
# => NoMethodError
Bar.new.blah
# => 'blah'
```

Here you can see the differences in behavior of `include` and `extend`. To verify their behavior with regards to class ancestry, you can ask for the ancestors of `Bar` and its singleton class, and it will show you that module `Blah` is the immediate parent of `Bar`, but module `Foo` is the immediate parent of the singleton class.

```
Bar.ancestors
# => [Bar, Blah, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Bar.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [Foo, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

From these results, you can see how inclusion emulates inheritance in the including class, and how extension is merely inclusion within the singleton class.

You might try looking at the answers I got for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552915/ruby-mixins-extend-and-include) awhile back; they did an excellent job of explaining the behavior of the `include` and `extend` functionality.
[This article](http://erniemiller.org/2012/11/29/ruby-tidbit-include-vs-extend-with-module-class-variables/) has also helped me understand their differences.