# Ruby mixins: extend and include

Tags: ruby, inheritance, include, extend

I've been reading a few articles about Ruby's mixin methods, `extend` and `include`, and I am still not quite sure about the behavior. I understand that `extend` will add the instance methods of the given module as singleton methods to the module doing the extending, and that `include` will essentially append the contents of a module (methods, constants, variables) to the one doing the including, effectively defining them in the receiver.

However, after some tinkering, trying to get a feel for how the behavior will manifest, I've got a few questions. Here is my testing setup:

```
module Baz
  def blorg
    puts 'blorg'
  end
end

module Bar
  include Baz
  def blah
    puts 'blah'
  end
end

module Foo
  extend Bar
end

class Bacon
  extend Bar
end

class Egg
  include Bar
end
```

So as I would expect, module `Bar` gains the instance methods defined in `Baz` (`#blorg`) as if they'd been defined in itself due to the inclusion method, and class `Bacon` gains the singleton methods `Bacon::blah` and `Bacon::blorg` by extension.

```
Bacon.blah  # => blah
Bacon.blorg # => blorg
```

And class `Egg` gains the methods defined in `Bar` (`#blah` and now `#blorg`) as instance methods.

```
Egg.new.blah  # => blah
Egg.new.blorg # => blorg
```

I get all that, so that's good.

However, I don't understand the responses I get from using the `#ancestors` and `#is_a?` methods.

```
Bacon.ancestors  # => [Bacon, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Bacon.is_a? Bar  # => true

Egg.ancestors    # => [Egg, Bar, Baz, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Egg.is_a? Bar    # => false
```

It would seem that extending a module causes the `#is_a?` method to return `true` when queried about that module, but it is not added to the ancestors of the class, and vice versa with regards to inclusion: the ancestors of the class contains the modules being included, but the `#is_a?` method returns `false` when queried. Why does this happen?

Comment: +1 for the great format of this question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The difference is that `include` will add the included class to the ancestors of the including class, whereas `extend` will add the extended class to the ancestors of the extending classes' singleton class. Phew. Let's first observe what happens:

```
Bacon.ancestors
#=> [Bacon, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Bacon.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [Bar, Baz, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Bacon.new.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [Bacon, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Bacon.is_a? Bar
#=> true

Bacon.new.is_a? Bar
#=> false
```

And for the `Egg` class

```
Egg.ancestors
#=> [Egg, Bar, Baz, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Egg.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Egg.new.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [Egg, Bar, Baz, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Egg.is_a? Bar
#=> false

Egg.new.is_a? Bar
#=> true
```

So what `foo.is_a? Klass` actually does is to check whether `foo.singleton_class.ancestors` contains `Klass`. The other thing happening is that all the ancestors of a class become ancestors of an instances' singleton class when the instance is created. So this will evaluate to true for all newly created instances of any class:

```
Egg.ancestors == Egg.new.singleton_class.ancestors
```

So what does all this mean? `extend` and `include` do the same thing on different levels, i hope the following example makes this clear as both ways to extend a class are essentially equivalent:

```
module A
  def foobar
    puts 'foobar'
  end
end

class B
  extend A
end

class C
  class << self
    include A
  end
end

B.singleton_class.ancestors == C.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> true
```

where `class << self` is just the odd syntax to get to the singleton class. So `extend` really just is a shorthand for `include` in the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Egg.is_a? Egg # => false
```

The include (effectively) changes instances of the `Egg` class. Although it isn't quite the same, it is very similar to doing something like

```
class Egg < Bar
end
```

When the extend will add class methods, so this is very similar to doing something like

```
class Bacon
  class << self
    include Bar
  end
end
```

You can think of it like include changes instances of the class, where as extend actually changes the class.

Comment: perhaps you mis-typed something, but when I do `Egg.new.is_a? Egg` it returns `true`. Did you mean `Egg.is_a? Egg  # => false`?