# Ruby: How do I call a child class using a method inside my parent class?

Tags: ruby, module

I'm trying to call CurrentPlan::Subscription inside CurrentPlan using a method named `subscriptions`. I have 2 files. Here is my code

`current_plan.rb`

```
require_relative 'current_plan/subscription'

class CurrentPlan
  # Get all subscriptions through current_plan
  def subscriptions
    CurrentPlan::Subscription.all
  end
end

current_plan = CurrentPlan.new()
current_plan.subscriptions
```

`current_plan/subscription.rb`

```
require_relative '../current_plan'

class CurrentPlan::Subscription
  def self.all
    %w[subscription_1 subscription_2 subscription_3]
  end
end
```

The Error I receive.

```
<CurrentPlan:0x0000010191ebd0>
/Users/foobar/Sites/ruby_apps/current_plan.rb:18:in `subscriptions': uninitialized     constant CurrentPlan::Subscription (NameError)
from /Users/foobar/Sites/ruby_apps/current_plan.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/foobar/Sites/ruby_apps/current_plan/subscription.rb:3:in `require_relative'
from /Users/foobar/Sites/ruby_apps/current_plan/subscription.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from current_plan.rb:14:in `require_relative'
from current_plan.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Fyi, this isn't how you do inheritance in Ruby. What you're doing here is namespacing, not inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

In `current_plan/subscription.rb`, change to:

```
require_relative '../current_plan'

class CurrentPlan
  class Subscription
    def self.all
      %w[subscription_1 subscription_2 subscription_3]
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby gets confused trying to resolve `CurrentPlan::Subscription` when it doesn't even really know what `CurrentPlan` is...

An alternative would be to put the `require` statement in `current_plan.rb` at the end of the file (after the class declaration), in which case you would not need to modify `subscription.rb`, but that could cause other problems down the line.

Comment: That will fix *a* problem, but not the one the OP is encountering right now.

Comment: @Ajedi32 What do you call this kind of class structure? Is this considered Inheritance?

Comment: @MarcSeifert See my comment on your question. This is called namespacing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here. The first is that you are `require`-ing files in a circle. If you look at the backtrace of your error, starting at the bottom, the first thing to be executed is the call to `require_relative 'current_plan/subscription'`. The first line in that file is a call to `require_relative '../current_plan'`, which is the original file which is already in the process of loading.

Ruby will now try to require this file, and will skip over the call to `require_relative 'current_plan/subscription'` since it recognises that the file has already been required (even though it hasn't finished being required). Defining the `CurrentPlan` class is okay, since even though the method references an undefined constant it isn’t called yet. When execution reaches the last two lines of `current_plan.rb` it creates a `CurrentPlan` instance and tries to call `subscriptions` on it. This is where the error occurs, since `subscriptions` refers to `CurrentPlan::Subscription` that hasn’t been defined yet (we still haven’t returned from the call to `require_relative` at the top of `subscription.rb`).

This behaviour only occurs when the file being required is the originally executed file, i.e. in this case you run `$ ruby current_plan.rb` and then call `require 'current_plan'` (or `require_relative`). If `current_plan` is required from another file then the `require_relative '../current_plan'` in `subscription.rb` will be skipped as Ruby will recognise that file as already having been required.

Fixing this is simple, jut remove the line

```
require_relative '../current_plan'
```

from `subscription.rb`. (You may need to make sure files other than `current_plan.rb` don’t try to require `subscriptions` directly).

Fixing that will expose the other problem. When trying to require `subscription` the class `CurrentPlan` hasn’t yet been defined, so `class CurrentPlan::Subscription` will fail.

There are a couple of ways to solve this, the most straightforward is to change

```
class CurrentPlan::Subscription
  ...
end
```

to

```
class CurrentPlan
  class Subscription
    ...
  end
end
```

so that you ensure `CurrentPlan` is defined when you try to define `Subscription`. Another way would be to move the call to `require_relative` in `current_plan.rb` below the definition of `CurrentPlan` (or even inside it).

Comment: this doesn't seem to be true. When I run the asker's code, the first `require` (in `current_plan.rb`) **completely** loads `subscription.rb` (that is, it skips the `require` in that file). However, I am also unable to replicate the asker's reported issue exactly (I encounter the issue addressed in my answer). What version of Ruby are you using? I've tried this with 1.9.3 and 2.0.0.

Comment: @kardeiz 2.1.2, I can also reproduce it with 2.0.0 and 1.9.3 (1.8.7 doesn’t have `require_relative`).

Comment: that's weird. When I run the asker's code, I get the uninitialized constant `CurrentPlan` issue. How are you loading this code? I'm launching `irb` from the directory root and then running `require './current_plan'`.

Comment: @kardeiz I’m just using `ruby current_plan.rb`. If I try it from IRB I get the same behaviour as you see. Also if I create another file containing just `require './current_plan' and run that then it works. It seems the originally executed file isn’t considered as have being required, so requiring it will result in the circular behaviour, whilst if it is required normally it will be skipped if seen again. I think that’s worth noting in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```rb
module A
  class Subscription
    def self.all
      puts "all method of Subscription" 
    end
  end
end

class CurrentPlan
  include A
  def subscriptions
    CurrentPlan::Subscription.all
  end
end

current_plan = CurrentPlan.new()
current_plan.subscriptions  # => all method of Subscription
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not trying to change my pattern, but just make my inherited file include accordingly whenever I call CurrentPlan::Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to inherit behaviour, simply use... well, inheritance. But be aware that Ruby does not support nested classes like, say, Java does.

If you want, the Inner class to extend the outer class, you can do:

```
class Outer

  class Inner < Outer
    def outer_method
      my_outer_method("hey!")
    end
  end

  def my_outer_method(foo)
    puts foo
  end

end

foo = Outer::Inner.new
foo.outer_method           #<= "hey!"
foo.my_outer_method("hi!") #<= "hi!"
```

Which is simpler, by the way.

You can still think about namespaces/modules, like:

```
module CurrentPlan #this is your namespace
end

class CurrentPlan::Subscription #this is your class
end

subs = CurrentPlan::Subscription.new #this is your instance
```

Although, in Ruby you cannot have an instance of a module (in this case CurrentPlan cannot be instantiated). But you can include the module's methods by using [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552915/ruby-mixins-extend-and-include).

Comment: I want to achieve this but using two separate files.. Please refer to my example. I edited it to make things clearer :-)

Comment: I know. You can declare the module/namespace in one file and the class in another file. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me! Appreciate everyone's help

```
current_plan.rb

require_relative 'current_plan/subscription'

class CurrentPlan
  def subscription
    CurrentPlan::Subscription.new
  end
end

current_plan = CurrentPlan.new
puts current_plan.subscription.all
```

```
current_plan/subscription.rb

class CurrentPlan
  class Subscription
    def all
      %w[asd asdadsadasdas njasdnjasndjasd subscription_1 subscription_2]
    end
  end
end
```